# "It is a distutils installed project ..." when calling install_mlflow()

Tags: r, rstudio, mlflow

When `install_mlflow()` is called to install mlflow for R, the following error is encountered.

> Attempting uninstall: certifi
> Found existing installation: certifi 2018.4.16
> ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'certifi'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

**Note:** The above is using `miniconda` installed using `install_miniconda()` command.

---

P.S. Posting question & answer for everyone's benefit (I spend 2 days on this).

Answer (score 0):

**Root cause:**

The function `install_mlflow()`calls `reticulate::conda_install()` function with the default value for `pip_ignore_installed` which turns out to be `FALSE`.

> **Hint:** Click any function in the script while holding down cmd key to view the source code.

**Workaround:**

You can work around this issue by calling the function with `pip_ignore_installed = TRUE`. I've recreated the `install_mlflow()` function in the below script for convenience.

The script also checks and installs `miniconda` if not installed.

```
library(reticulate)
library(mlflow)


# Installing minicoda if not installed
if (!dir.exists(miniconda_path()))
  install_miniconda(path = miniconda_path(), update = TRUE, force = TRUE)

# install_mlflow() # This doesn't work so we use the alt fn below.
install_mlflow_alt <- function() {
  mlflow_version <- utils::packageVersion("mlflow")
  packages <- c(paste("mlflow", "==", mlflow_version, sep = ""))
  # Geting mlflow conda bin
  conda_home <- Sys.getenv("MLFLOW_CONDA_HOME", NA)
  conda <- if (!is.na(conda_home)) {
    paste(conda_home, "bin", "conda", sep = "/")
  } else {
    "auto"
  }
  conda_try <- try(conda_binary(conda = conda), silent = TRUE)
  if (class(conda_try) == "try-error") {
    msg <- paste(attributes(conda_try)$condition$message, 
                 paste("  If you are not using conda, you can set the environment variable", 
                       "MLFLOW_PYTHON_BIN to the path of your python executable."), 
                 sep = "\n")
    stop(msg)
  }
  conda <- conda_try
  # Installing mlflow
  mlflow_conda_env_name <- paste("r-mlflow", mlflow_version, sep = "-")
  conda_install(packages, envname = mlflow_conda_env_name, 
                pip = TRUE, conda = conda, pip_ignore_installed = TRUE)
}

# NOTE: Run the following command in terminal (use pip3 for python 3)
#       before calling the install_mlflow_alt() function below
# paste("pip install -U mlflow==", mlflow:::mlflow_version(), sep="")
install_mlflow_alt()
```